# Create Mapped Drive then copy contents over

Tags: batch-file

I was having an issue with a command in .bat files.  I was creating a mapped drive to the first device available.  Then I wanted to copy a folder from that network share to a location in C:\temp.  Here is where I'm at currently.

```
net use * \\SomeComputer\exp\Reinstaller_PROD\TunerReinstPROD
copy \*.TunerReinstPROD  "C:\\temp%~p1"
```

I was trying to copy the contents over to C:\temp.  What am I missing?  Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

The `net use` command does not change the working directly, so unless the working directly is already set to `\\SomeComputer\exp\Reinstaller_PROD\TunerReinstPROD` the copy command is going to look for `*.TurnerReinstPROD` in the wrong place.

Do something like this:  ( I am changing the working directory to the newly mapped drive. )

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in ('net use * \\SomeComputer\exp\Reinstaller_PROD\TunerReinstPROD') do if "%%A"=="Drive" pushd %%B
copy *.TunerReinstPROD "C:\Temp%~p1"
popd
```

However, you should not even need the mapped drive if you use the `xcopy` or `robocopy` command.

```
@echo off
xcopy \\SomeComputer\exp\Reinstaller_PROD\TunerReinstPROD\*.TunerReinstPROD "C:\Temp%~p1"
```